# Why am I getting an 'Expected type expression but received "Model"' error when declaring a Flask-SQLAlchemy model class?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask_sqlalchemy, I have a file where are my models, when declare a class any(db.Model) I got this **Expected type expression but received "Model"**, somebody can help me please

I tried to connect my db to my app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.